# javascript not executing at all

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I've got below code but javascript doesn't seem to be executing at all.

Is there something that I am missing from here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Backbonejs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize: function(){
                console.log('hello world');
                this.bind('change:name', function(){
                    console.log(this.get('name') + "is now the val for name");
                });
            },
            defaults: {
                name: "Bob hope",
                height: "unknown"
            },
            validate: function(attributes){
                if(attributes.name == "Joe"){
                    return "Uh oh, you're name is Joe!";
                }
            }
        });

        var person = new Person();
        person.set({name: "Joe", height: "6 feet"});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have jQuery included. Backbone's only hard dependency is underscore.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing closing `script` tags, they are mandatory:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[...]underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="[...]backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Without them, it looks like Backbone is never loaded.

Comment: I should have known this! I feel really dumb now. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score -2):

If you don't have any errors in browser, that means that you have to execute this code when the page is loaded or include the jQuery library.